# My carousel pictures won't show up on the slider. I get a 'GET local_image_path 404(not found)' error on my browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carousel

I am using the carousel slider for my one page app. Everything works perfectly, the only issue is that the pictures won't show up when I run the server. On the browser it gives me an error 'GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/car.jpg 404 (Not Found)' for each of the images, with its respective path. I have tried most of the solutions online, yet nothing seems to work.

```
<body>
        <div class="carousel-container">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="../assets/images/VedadoPoster.jpg" alt="Poster" />
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="../assets/images/car.jpg" alt="Car" />
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="../assets/images/beach.jpg" alt="Beach" />
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="../assets/images/pool.jpg" alt="Flower"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: do you mean `http://localhost:3000/assets/images/car.jpg` doesn't return image but 404 error?You have checked all images exist?

Comment: where are your images placed?

Comment: all images exist and they were in my local files under assets/images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this .....

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <%= image_tag 'VedadoPoster.jpg' %>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <%= image_tag 'car.jpg' %>  
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <%= image_tag 'beach.jpg' %>  
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <%= image_tag 'pool.jpg' %>   
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this will work for you...............

Comment: @ManuelMoreno : Welcome ! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the path, If you have the images in `/assets/images` path.
You can change the code to,

```
   <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="/assets/images/VedadoPoster.jpg" alt="Poster" />
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="/assets/images/car.jpg" alt="Car" />
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="/assets/images/beach.jpg" alt="Beach" />
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="/assets/images/pool.jpg" alt="Flower"/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Or,

```
 <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
         <%= image_tag 'VedadoPoster.jpg' %>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <%= image_tag 'car.jpg' %>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <%= image_tag 'beach.jpg' %>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <%= image_tag 'pool.jpg' %>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Eg:

```
image_tag("icon")
# => <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/icon" />
image_tag("icon.png")
# => <img alt="Icon" src="/assets/icon.png" />
image_tag("icon.png", size: "16x10", alt: "Edit Entry")
# => <img src="/assets/icon.png" width="16" height="10" alt="Edit Entry" />
image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", size: "16")
# => <img src="/icons/icon.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Icon" />
image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", height: '32', width: '32')
# => <img alt="Icon" height="32" src="/icons/icon.gif" width="32" />
image_tag("/icons/icon.gif", class: "menu_icon")
# => <img alt="Icon" class="menu_icon" src="/icons/icon.gif" />
```

[Here is the reference](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag)